# ME tile can be unpinned? If so how can I pin it again?

Tags: 7.x, tiles

Looks like I can unpin the "ME" tile like every other tile. But I can't find where I can pin it again to start screen.

I already think about testing this by unpinning it but I'm afraid I can't find a place where can I pin it again.

**Someone already tried unpin "ME" tile? Where can you pin it again?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Open the people application.
2. Tap your avatar on the main page (with the 'all' heading).
3. Tap the pin icon.

Comment: By a moment I was afraid I didn't work. So a read again the second step. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working. Also, to be more correct I should say 'tap', 'touch' or 'press' instead of 'click'.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work like this in WP8.1 anymore. 

Comment: Just realized that in WP8.1 after the second step there is no "pin" button. But in my experience after just accessing this info the tile is automatically pinned at the bottom of your start screen.